# problem displaying blade file getting error '' count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable ''

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am having issues returning the view on my website i keep getting this error

```
ErrorException
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cargo\resources\views\shipment\single.blade.php)
```

and this error points to a section in my blade file which is causing it, below is my blade file for the view

```
 <div class="card" >
    <div class="card-body ">
        @if(count($shipment) >0)
       @foreach($shipment as $shipment)

                <div class="shipment-number">
        <span class="title" style="display: block; font-size: 25px!important;">{{$shipment->tracking_code }}</span>
    </div><!-- Track_Num -->
</div>
<br><br>

<div id="shipper-info" class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-6 detail-section">
            <p class="shipper details"><strong>Shipper's Information</strong></p>
            <div class="shipper details">
            <p><span class="label">Shipper Name : </span>{{$shipment->sender_name }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Phone Number : </span>{{$shipment->telephone }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Email : </span>{{$shipment->sender_email }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Address : </span>{{$shipment->sender_address }}</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 detail-section">
            <p class="shipper details"><strong>Receiver's Information</strong></p>
            <div class="receiver details">
            <p><span class="label">Receiver Name : </span>{{$shipment->receiver_name }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Phone Number : </span>{{$shipment->receiver_telephone }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Address : </span>{{$shipment->receiver_address }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Email : </span>{{$shipment->receiver_email }}</p>        
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="clear-line"></div>
</div>
@endforeach
@esle
@endif
```

and the error points to this section

```
@if(count($shipment) >0)
       @foreach($shipment as $shipment)
```

here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Shipment;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;




class ShipmentController extends Controller
{
   
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return \App\Shipment
     */
    protected function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        $shipment = new Shipment();

        $data  = $this->validate($request, [
            'sender_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'sender_email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'receiver_email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'sender_address' => 'required|string',
            'estimated_Date' => 'required||date|after:today',
            'shipment_type' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'content' => 'required|string|max:255', 
            'receiver_name' => 'required|string|max:255', 
            'receiver_address' => 'required|string|max:255', 
            'sender_country' => 'required|string|max:255', 
            'sender_telephone' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'comments' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'receiver_telephone' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'receiver_country' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'package_weight' => 'required|string|max:255',
            
        ]);
        

        $shipment->sender_name = $request->input('sender_name');
        $shipment->receiver_email= $request->input('receiver_email');
        $shipment->sender_email= $request->input('sender_email');
        $shipment->sender_address= $request->input('sender_address');
        $shipment->estimated_Date= $request->input('estimated_Date');
        $shipment->shipment_type= $request->input('shipment_type');
        $shipment->content= $request->input('content');
        $shipment->receiver_name= $request->input('receiver_name');
        $shipment->receiver_address= $request->input('receiver_address');
        $shipment->sender_country= $request->input('sender_country');
        $shipment->sender_telephone= $request->input('sender_telephone');
        $shipment->comments= $request->input('comments');
        $shipment->receiver_telephone= $request->input('receiver_telephone');
        $shipment->receiver_country= $request->input('receiver_country');
        $shipment->package_weight= $request->input('package_weight');
        $shipment->tracking_code = strtoupper(Str::random(20));
        
        $shipment->save();   

           
            return redirect('/index')->with('Success', 'Your Shipment has been created');
       
    }

    public function tracking(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request,
            [
                'tracking_code' => 'required|max:25',

            ]);

        $shipment = Shipment::where('tracking_code', $request->input('tracking_code'))->first();
        
        if ( $shipment == null)
        {
            
            return redirect('/shipment/track')->with('error', 'Incorect Tracking Number');
            
        }
        else{
            return view('shipment.single')->with('shipment', $shipment);
        }

    }



    public function view(Shipment $shipment){

        $page_title = "view shipment";
        

       
        if (Gate::allows('isAdmin')) {
           return view('shipment.single',compact('shipment'. title));
    }
            
    else {
        return redirect('/home')->with('error', 'Unauthorized Page');
    }
```

and my routes

```
Route::Post('/tracking', 'ShipmentController@tracking')->name('tacking');
Route::get('/shipment/view/{shipment}', 'ShipmentController@view')->name('shipment.view');
```

i cant get around this and have been on it for a while now , any help will be appriciated, i would like for the view to be shown along with all the data parsed for both the input(tracking function) and the single blade (view function)

Comment: Change `->first();` to `->get();`

Comment: thanks alot missed that , worked for the tracking function would appriciate if you could look into the view function for what i missed or any other oprions to explore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to apply loop on single record as you can see it's single record.

```
<div class="card" >
        <div class="card-body ">
    
                <div class="shipment-number">
        <span class="title" style="display: block; font-size: 25px!important;">{{$shipment->tracking_code }}</span>
    </div><!-- Track_Num -->
</div>
<br><br>

<div id="shipper-info" class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-6 detail-section">
            <p class="shipper details"><strong>Shipper's Information</strong></p>
            <div class="shipper details">
            <p><span class="label">Shipper Name : </span>{{$shipment->sender_name }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Phone Number : </span>{{$shipment->telephone }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Email : </span>{{$shipment->sender_email }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Address : </span>{{$shipment->sender_address }}</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 detail-section">
            <p class="shipper details"><strong>Receiver's Information</strong></p>
            <div class="receiver details">
            <p><span class="label">Receiver Name : </span>{{$shipment->receiver_name }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Phone Number : </span>{{$shipment->receiver_telephone }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Address : </span>{{$shipment->receiver_address }}</p>
            <p><span class="label">Email : </span>{{$shipment->receiver_email }}</p>        
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="clear-line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calling `->first()` which is going to return one shipment as opposed to a collection of shipments, you can use `->get()` or `->paginate()` to get a collection of the models back then iterate over them in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `->first()` when fetching data, use `->get() or ->paginate(x)` instead so you can get a collection.

in your blade file, the foreach Loop you are using the same variable as collection and as single data

```
@foreach($shipment as $shipment)
```

i recomand you use `$shipments` for collection as variable and $shipment for the instance.

> x just a number